# to put down root + "in which" or postponed "in"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

What should I say?

> The second theory **in which** my concept puts down roots is TheoryName

or

> The second theory my concept puts down roots **in** is TheoryName

In the latter version, what about a comma after *in* ("[...] *puts down roots in`,` is* [...]")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recognise this use of the idiom "put down roots". To me, the only meaning of that phrase is when somebody goes to live somewhere new, and starts to feel that this is their home, and make connections. I would substitute "is rooted" or "has its roots".

To answer your question, either is fine. The form with "in which"

> The second theory in which my theory is rooted is ...

is more formal, and many people would think it more appropriate for a scholarly paper. But

> The second theory my concept is rooted in is ...

is normal, and for some people acceptable even in scholarly writing.

Comment: Thank you for correcting it idiomatically, and especially for explaining *how formal* are both version. In the first version, should there be a comma after "rooted" ? ("*The second theory in which my theory is rooted **,** is...*")

Comment: I don't usually comment on matters of fashion, such as punctuation and spelling, as I'm not very interested in them. But last time I looked, the people who regarded themselves as authorities in these matters said you shouldn't put a comma after the subject, even a long subject like "The second theory my concept is rooted in". I think this "rule" is silly: when reading a sentence like this one out, you might pause after the subject for clarity, and you might not; therefore in my view you may use a comma but don't have to. I don't know whether the punctuation gurus are still saying that or not.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I thought, that there was a precise rule in this case, but I couldn't find it. Hence my question (that should have been "*Must* there be a comma...").